# Unsupervised Sentiment Analysis on product reviews

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, nlp

I would like to perform an unsupervised sentiment analysis on the reviews posted by customers on different product web-page. Most of the online resources use supervised methods and the examples/tutorials always have a labelled training data-set.

My objective is not to just deduce the polarity of the review but also do content/subjective analysis. Any online implementation or suggest high level approach for this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to datascience.SE

Comment: Could you please clarify more?

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow, but it is on topic for datasxience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

One unsupervised approach you can take is word vector embedding along with k-means clustering. Here's an example in Python http://brandonrose.org/clustering

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 3 years later but since there is no accepted answer imma answer it.

`My objective is not to just deduce the polarity of the review but also do content/subjective analysis.` You can do just this with the help of a library called **`TextBlob`**. Here is a [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/natural-language-processing-for-beginners-using-textblob/) to an article where it is mentioned how to get polarity and subjectivity from a string using `TextBlob`.